# Typescript, transform interface keys into enum of possible string values

Tags: typescript

Let's pretend that I have an interface like so:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  keyA: string;
  keyB: number;
  keyC: boolean;
}
```

From this interface, I would like to dynamically create a union type that has 'keyA', 'keyB' and  'keyC' as possible values.

If I had to manually create it, it would result in something like:

```
export type MyType = 'keyA' | 'keyB' |'keyC';
```

Is that possible to achieve with Typescript?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
export type MyType = keyof MyInterface;
```

Comment: Just found it in the docs! Thanks for the quick answer though! I had also tried `typeof keyof MyInterface`

Comment: The `typeof` is only needed when you are getting keys from a javascript variable, ie. the implementation rather than the definition.  You don't need it here because `MyInterface` is already a type (`interface` and `type` have minor differences but are essentially synonymous when defining object types).